# How to slow down video, but not sound on the clip in iMovie?

Tags: imovie

I have a clip I want to show with slow motion. That clip has a soundtrack, but I need to **slow only video without sound**? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Split the audio from the video with Detach Audio (⌥⌘B), then you can retime the video independently.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the clip you wish to edit, and then detach the audio.  You can now manipulate the video without affecting the sound.